# Can not su - root. su: incorrect password

Tags: root, su

I am trying to switch to root user using the  su command.

I am  getting the following error

```
$ su - root
Password: 
su: incorrect password
```

I checked the /var/log/messages  and found the following:

```
Dec  9 17:04:27 vSBC_OMM_L audispd: node=vSBC_OMM_L type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1575929067.716:33815689): user pid=5855 uid=503 auid=0 ses=39383 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0 msg='op=PAM:authentication acct="root" exe="/bin/su" hostname=? addr=? terminal=pts/0 res=failed'
```

In addition the permissions of /bin/su are:

```
-rwsr-sr-x. 1 root root   34904 Jul 25  2017 su
```

Comment: Some systems do not have a password for `root` by default and they have just `sudo` configured. What system are you using? You can try `sudo passwd` to (re)set root's password.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I updated the password as you suggested, but the problem is still present. I am using RHEL 6

Comment: Does `sudo su -` work?

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. I just followed the steps of this  [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_OpenStack_Platform/2/html/Getting_Started_Guide/ch02s03.html)